# Display a Checkbox Yes and Checkbox No

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a field called PermanentAddressChk saved within the database as a bit.

I need to display 2 checkboxes ‘Yes’ and ‘No’ for PermanentAddressChk field.

The following code works ok, but is there a better way to do this? Open to new ideas, cheers.

```
<br />@Html.Label("Yes")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PermanentAddressChk, htmlAttributes: new { @checked = true })
<br />&nbsp @Html.Label("No")
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.PermanentAddressChk, htmlAttributes: new { @checked = false})
```

Comment: So they both can be checked?    Radio buttons are use for multiple selections options where only one option can be selected.

Answer (score 2):

I know you said you were looking for two checkboxes, but here's an example of yes/no radiobuttons in case that's of any interest.

```
<div id="radioButtonDiv" >
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PermanentAddressChk, "Is address permanent?")
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PermanentAddressChk, true, new { id = "isPermanentAddressTrue" }) @Html.Label("isPermanentAddressTrue", "Yes")
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.PermanentAddressChk, false, new { id = "isPermanentAddressFalse" }) @Html.Label("isPermanentAddressFalse", "No")
    </div>
</div>
```

This allows you to reference the bool value from the controller with the single PermanentAddressChk property as well as the individual radio button values via javascript.  This also displays 'Yes/No' next to the radio button options.

Answer (score 1):

You could do like this:

View => You just need one check box, because if is not check you will receive a false in the controller.

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.PermanentAddressChk, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.PermanentAddressChk)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Active)
    </div>
</div>
```

in the View Model insert this:

```
[Display(Name = "Permanent Address ?")] // This will appear in your label
public bool PermanentAddressChk { get; set; }
```

Css =>

```
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.control-label {
 padding-top: 7px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 text-align: right;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys much appreciated.